# insert into sql statement with where clause

Tags: mysql

I would like to get help for the mentioned problem below:

SQL query: Copy

```
INSERT INTO kurs SET name='Bangla', freiePlaetze=10 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ersteller=1
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`learner`.`kurs`, CONSTRAINT `kurs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
> (`ersteller`) REFERENCES `benutzer` (`bnummer`))

Comment: And is there a related record in benutzer.bnummer for that ersteller?

Comment: Insert is used when you want to add a new record. For an insert you're providing values for all fields (or at least the fields that mandate they can't be null). I think you want to update instead, that will let you uldayia single field with a where clause to match certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You've told MySQL "Insert into the kurs table, these values.. and if they already exist, change the `ersteller` column of the existing row so its value is 1"

But `ersteller` is linked to a parent column `bnummer` in the `bnutzer` table, and there is no row where `bnummer = 1`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90ab193e86d661b4341343efc459b492

Insert a row into `benutzen` first, where the `bnummer` column is 1